# Firefox Browser on Android Has Grey Highlighting on Links

Tags: android, html, css, firefox, mobile

I am having issues trying to modify the grey highlight colour of links when viewing in a Firefox Browser on Android Phones.

So say I have a button that is an  tag such as: nav and the button is round. So when I click on it there is a grey highlight colour that is square which makes it look like a mistake.

I've tried using: -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(29, 30, 32, 1); but of course that only works for Chrome and I can't seem to find a Firefox equivalent.

This only happens on  tags.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set

`a:active{background:transparent}`

PS. For Safari, you'll need to set `ontouchstart="return true"` on `<body>` for that to work too.